# Set some type of alert on our Opportunity page

Tags: pagemessages

I have something else that is throwing me for a loop. I hope I can explain this ok.

I have our Opportunity page that I have a request to put some type of alert on.  This could be a label or a text box or the like. Preferably in larger text or better yet, highlighted in red if at all possible (can font size or color be set?).

What optimally should happen is I have a custom pick-list field (or could be a check box too) on the Opportunity page. In the case of the pick-list, if the user selects "Conditional Approval", some type of indicator alert should show on the Opportunity page every time it loads until the "Conditional Approval" is changed to "Approved" or blank.

In the Approval process, in an Approval Step, I have an action using a Field Update that is supposed to add text to a custom text field (because I can't find a label object to use) that I put at the top of the Opportunity page. Right now the code in this step looks like this:

```
IF(ispickval( Approval_Status__c , "Conditional Approval"),   
   "This Opportunity has a Conditional Approval!",  "")
```

If the Approval Status list = "Conditional Approval" then set the text to "This Opportunity has a Conditional Approval!", otherwise blank. At least I think this is what it does.

So far, it's not really doing anything.  I guess what I'm looking for is a way to set some kind of an alert on our Opportunity page if the pick-list has "Conditional Approval" set (or a checkbox could be selected...either way). It can run from the Approval Process we have set or another way. Preferably from the Approval Process page in case they want to add something else like email or whatever they can think of.

Sorry to sound so **noob**, but I have never touched SalesForce and the person who did it for years left a few weeks ago and I got delegated this project. I've never done Java either so I'm feeling my way around that too. All this adds up to a real "Not Having a Clue" factor.  Thanks for ANY help you can be!!!  I do appreciate it!!

If this sounds vague, confusing or more detailed info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a formula field displaying an image indicator ?

example formula:

```
IF (NOT(ISBLANK(text(alertChekBox__c))) , IMAGE("/img/msg_icons/error24.png", "high risk") , "")
```

This uses a salesforce icon so that should work in any org. Just got to plug in the right field and possible condition.

This will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Just a supplement to @Sdry's answer. You can find the Salesforce native icons here: http://free-121d5f44d20-121d603d1c5-121ee2b8103.force.com/force2b/salesforceicons

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. 
1) Download an image that suites your requirement for alert
2) upload it in staticresources and name it something like "alertImage"
3) create a formula field in opportunity like
IF (
ispickval( Approval_Status__c , "Conditional Approval") , 
IMAGE("/resource/alertImage", "This Opportunity has a Conditional Approval!") , 
"")
4) Add the formula field on you page layout at top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sdry Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look at that.

Comment: This looks like what I could use. Except right now I can't get the custom fields to show in the Approve/Reject Approval Request section.  Strange...the labels for the field show up. SalesForce is still an enigma to me!  I'll let you know how your suggestion worked when I figure my new problem out.  Thanks everyone for your suggestions!